# Entity Framework - Code Firts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Si tengo una aplicacion de escritorio(Windows Forms) desarrollado con EF code firts pero la conexión a la base de datos de mi pc es autentificacion Windows(al servidor SQL).
Pero al llevarla a otra pc tienen un servidor SQL con autentificación SQL usuario y password, al ejecutar mi aplicación ¿se crearía la base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partamos de la base que el tipo de autenticacion no tiene ninguna relacion con la creacion o no de la base de datos.

Ademas de por si EF no crea la base de datos, salvo que lo definas en la configuracion de inicializacion

[Database Initialization Strategies in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

pero podrias definir otras estrategias como ser que actualice en caso de encontrar diferencia con el modelo o simplemente que no haga nada (con lo cual tendrias un exception).

Por una lado esta la forma en que te autenticas y otra seria el Source y Database que defines en el connection string, podrias definir dos formas distintas de autenticacion (integrada a windows o por medio de usuario y password) y ambas conectarse normalmente a la misma base de datos.

Comment: Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación por primera vez si me creea la base de datos y las tablas en el SQL.

Comment: recuerda que por defecto usa CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, salvo que definas lo contrario, es por eso que crea la db

Answer (score 1):

No andaria, tengo entendido que tendrias que configurar ese user y pass de sql cuando configuras el EF en tu app.
Lo que podrias probar seria configurar ese usuario y pass en el EF, luego compilar y llevarte los DLLs a la "otra pc". Saludos

Comment: porque hay que compilar para configurar el usuario y password ? esta usando code first y el connection string nodeberia estar fijo en el codigo sino en el app.config con lo cual puede cambiarse la autenticacion sin tener que recompilar

Comment: lo que te digo es que configures el usuario y pass en EF y luego compiles para podes usar los DLL de la aplicacion en tu otra pc.

Comment: ok pero eso como responde al planteo de crear o no la db si defines medios de autenticacion distintos en el connection string? porque entiendo le sugieres que lo pruebe, pero si lo haces entonces no hubiera planteado la pregunta